# What does a period do between a variable and an array?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-address, period

I'm learning C and trying to understand what the period "." is doing with the variables x and a; what is this operation called, and what does it do?

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Create a structure called myStructure
struct T {
    int *a;
    struct T* next;
};
int *y;
int **z;
struct T   x;
struct T*  p1;
struct T*  p2;
struct T** p3;

int main()
{   p1 = (struct T*)malloc(sizeof(struct T));
    p2 = &x ;
    y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    {int* a[3];
    a[1] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
     z = &a[1];        
     x.a  = *z;                     // point 1
     (*p1).a = *z;                  // point 2
   }             
   (*p1).next = p1;                 // point 3
   p2 = p1;                         // point 4
   p3 = &p1;                        // point 5
   p3 = *(&p3) ;                    // point 6
   p3 = &(*p3) ;                    // point 7
   x.a = y ;                        // point 8
   z = x.a ;                        // point 9
   free(x.a);                       // point 10
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified i'm refering to point 1

Comment: `x.y` designates the member named `y` of the structure `x`.

Comment: Search "c dot operator"

Comment: If `a` is a `struct` or `union`, and contains a field named `b`, then `a.b` refers to the the `b` field of `a`.  If `p` is a pointer to a `struct` or `union`, and the `struct` or `union` contains a field named `b`, then `p->b` refers to the `b` field of the `struct` or `union` pointed to by `p`.  Note that `p->b` is equivalent to `(*p).b`.

Comment: Thank you all! this pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator is called structure/union member operator (curiously enough only referenced in the index that way).  It does not apply to arrays.  The type `struct T` has two members `a` and `next`.  `struct T x;` defines an object `x` of the type `struct T` and the expression `x.a` means access the member `a` of the object `x`.  Related is the arrow operator `->` which does the same thing except the left hand side is an pointer such as `(&x)->a`, or `p1->a`.

Here's the relevant section from C17 specification, 6.5.2.3, p. 59:

> A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,97) and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue. If the first expression has qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.

> A postfix expression followed by the-> operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member of the object to which the first expression points, and is an lvalue.98) If the first expression is a pointer to a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.